# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my code:

```
for x in header:
    testvar = x.find('strong')
    testvar2 = testvar.contents[0]
    print(testvar2)
```

And here's my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\Personal Folders\Andy\Python Projects\Salesforce BZ API\Automated Reports.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(testvar2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 74, in _reduce_ex
    getstate = self.__getstate__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 655, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__, tag)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

I'm not sure why it won't let me select the contents of the strong tag, any idea? I'm also having trouble getting these values back into the list header.

Here's the full code to generate header:

```
from __future__ import division
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
import spynner
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#Loading up Salesforce

br = spynner.Browser()
#br.debug_level = spynner.DEBUG
br.create_webview()
br.show()
br.set_html_parser(BeautifulSoup)
br.load("https://login.salesforce.com/")
br.fill("input[name=username]", "USERNAME")
br.fill("input[name=pw]", "PASSWORD")
br.click("input[name=Login]", wait_load=True)
br.load("https://na8.salesforce.com/00OC0000004jUDu")
html = br.soup()

html = [str(x) for x in html]

html = ''.join(html)

html = BeautifulSoup(html)

header = html.find('form', {'id': 'report'})
header = header.find('div', {'class': 'bGeneratedReport'})
header = header.find('div', {'class': 'reportOutput'})
header = header.find('tbody')
header = header.findAll('th')
```

Comment: If you look at the exception raised, it is trying to format `tag` as a string, which is going to call `tag.__str__` to do so, which is the `__str__` method in the Tag class (I've looked at BeautifulSoup.py). I presume the `__str__` method is accidentally asking for the string format of another instance of Tag, thus causing the infinite recursion. You can easily add print statements to BeautifulSoup.py to see what is going on.

Comment: The error is actually being raised in the print statement, apparently while BeautifulSoup is trying to generate an error message about a missing attribute. My bet is that whatever class is involved here has a faulty `__str__()` method that uses `str()` on itself, getting stuck in an infinite recursion. I can't reproduce this with a simple test case so I agree, it probably has to do with where `header` comes from.

Comment: So, does anyone have any additional ideas?